# Why was I notified of this comment?

Tags: support, bug, status-declined, comments, notifications

I commented on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39065220/how-to-get-count-of-a-particular-item-from-table-using-mysql?noredirect=1#comment65479125_39065220) question,

[image]

Then the OP posted a comment not directed at me, it had someone else tagged and I was alerted.

**Notification**

[image]

**Comment by OP**

[image]

So,

**Why was I notified?**

It isn't a big deal to me, just curious how the notification system thought it had something to do with me?

Comment: Because there was nobody else for it to be a reply to, despite the tagging of Zain (not sure how they were involved). If there are no comments by anyone else, the system assumes the OP is replying to you.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

There is a deleted comment from Zain.

It was deleted 1 second before the OP posted their reply. So the @Zain would have been a response to that comment, but by the time it was actually posted yours was the only non-deleted comment - hence you got the notification.

I could argue that this is a bug, though not a very serious one.

Comment: Agreed - *bug*, though not serious. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: Definitely a race condition.  You should make people acquire a semaphore before being allowed to start writing their comment.